In-Place Reordering of Doubly Linked List Nodes to Ensure Memory Contiguity
I am working on a program that deals with doubly linked lists that are allocated within a bounded memory region:
constexpr std::size_t numNodes = 15;
Node* block = new Node[numNodes];

I would like to write a swap(Node* block, std::size_t i, std::size_t j) function that swaps two nodes' locations in memory, but ensures the traversal order of the linked list itself remains the same.
For example,
Before swapping indices 1 and 3:
List:  [A] -> [B] -> [C] -> [D]
Memory: 10, 20, 30, 40

After swapping indices 1 and 3:
List:  [A] -> [B] -> [C] -> [D]
Memory: 10, 40, 30, 20

Any ideas on how to correctly implement this?
I have an initial implementation, but it seems like this does not account for all possible edge cases. For example, it fails when the node at index i is a successor or predecessor of the node at index j (i.e., they are adjacent within the linked list, not necessarily memory itself).
Here is the implementation:
void swap(Node* array, int i, int j) {
  if (i == j)
    return;

  // Swap the nodes
  Node temp = array[i];
  array[i] = array[j];
  array[j] = temp;

  // Update next and prev pointers for array[i]
  if (array[i].next) {
    array[i].next->prev = &array[i];
  }
  if (array[i].prev) {
    array[i].prev->next = &array[i];
  }

  // Update next and prev pointers for array[j]
  if (array[j].next) {
    array[j].next->prev = &array[j];
  }
  if (array[j].prev) {
    array[j].prev->next = &array[j];
  }
}


Is this a circularly linked list?

No, the tail's next member will always be nullptr and head's prev member will always be nullptr.

This is not usual, as usual assignments require the changing of the link fields, not the data fields.

I'm not sure what you're referring to? The goal is to swap the nodes in memory, and adjust the link fields such that the original traversal order is preserved.

@ChrisMM Whatever do you mean? None of the expressions on the right side of the & operator are local variables.

How are you keeping track of which node is the head or the tail of the list? swap doesn't attempt any such tracking.

It looks like your algorithm attempts 2 things: (1) Swap the values stored in the node; (2) re-link each node in the position of the other. After doing both actions, traversing through the list would show the values in the original order, which contradicts your desired goal. Do just one of the two actions, i.e., either swap the nodes' values (but not the pointers), or re-link the nodes (but leave the values unchanged).

How could achieve the desired effect by exclusively swapping values?

I repeat Igor's question: How are you keeping track of which node is the head or the tail of the list?

Sentinel nodes will reduce the number of edge cases to zero.

Is tracking the head or tail needed? It could have unintended consequences on traversals post-swap, but it shouldn't impact the swap implementation, no?
For the sake of tracking, if we know the head and tail pre-swap we would know if we are swapping the head/tail, and if so, where the head/tail would be post-swap.

Sure, but then shouldn't the swap function manage that? What you are doing deviates a lot from OOP design.

I agree -- I would bake that into my actual implementation swap, but I feel that part of the implementation is not relevant to this question since I need help with making the swap itself work correctly.

If you don't know which node is the head, how do you plan to later traverse the list? If you can't traverse, how do you even know your algorithm does or doesn't work?

You can solve the edge conditions simply by declaring your array to 17 in length, i.e. creating an inaccessible dummy header and tail. Therefore all 15 inner elements will have a valid head and tail.

@IgorTandetnik, you're right. No idea what I was thinking.

This whole question is just “how to swap arbitrary nodes in a doubly-linked list (possibly without the usual sentinel nodes)?” (which should be a duplicate if the existing questions were better asked and answered) plus swapping the node contents (which typically merges with swapping the pointers to become swapping whole nodes) as the node swapping is usually meant to avoid.

I posted an answer to the one that searching suggests should be canonical, which is similar to Jonathon Halim’s below (great minds and all).

If nodes[i] and nodes[j] are adjacent within the linked list, the original code will result in either linking back to themselves.
The correct way to work around this is to "cache" the previous pointers first, then make the necessary swaps.
void swap(Node* block, std::size_t i, std::size_t j) {
  auto i_prev = block[i].prev;
  auto j_prev = block[j].prev;

  if (block[i].next) {
    block[i].next->prev = &block[j];
  }

  if (block[j].next) {
    block[j].next->prev = &block[i];
  }

  if (i_prev) {
    i_prev->next = &block[j];
  }

  if (j_prev) {
    j_prev->next = &block[i];
  }

  std::swap(block[i], block[j]);
}

This version also only has 4 branches, similar to the original implementation.

There's multiple solutions to implementing a swap(). For instance, we can leave the links alone, and just copy the value portion, e.g.
  // Swap the values only
  int tmp = array[i].value;
  array[i].value = array[j].value;
  array[j].value = tmp;

Or we can rewrite the pointers:
    array[i].prev.next = new_value_1;
    array[i].next.prev = new_value_2;
    array[i].next = new_value_3;
    array[i].prev = new_value_4;
    array[j].prev.next = new_value_5;
    array[j].next.prev = new_value_6;
    array[j].next = new_value_7;
    array[j].prev = new_value_8;

Doing the latter is harder but, in means that it is more optimal since we do not touch the value portion.
However, your swap will change both the value and pointer portions:
  // Swap the nodes
  Node temp = array[i];
  array[i] = array[j];
  array[j] = temp;

So, you need some effort to restore the pointer values to simulate the former.
Alternatively, I recommend to grow your array by an extra 2 nodes. The inner 4 nodes will have non-null prev and next pointers. We can access prev and next pointers without requiring null checks for the end cases.
There are 4 sub-cases to consider:

Special Case 1: i == j do nothing
Special Case 2: i + 1 == j, Resulting in a special new single sequence
Special Case 3: j + 1 == i, Resulting in another special new single sequence
Default Case 4: Resulting in two disjoint sequences

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

struct Node
{
  struct Node* next = nullptr;
  struct Node* prev = nullptr;
  int value = -1;
};

Node* new_array(std::size_t size)
{
  Node* array = new Node[size+2];
  for (int i = 0; i < size+2; i++)
  {
    array[i].next = (i<size+1) ? &array[i + 1] : nullptr;
    array[i].prev = (i>0) ? &array[i - 1] : nullptr;
    array[i].value = (i>0 && i <size+1) ? i * 10 : -1;
  }
  return array;
}

void print_array(Node* array)
{
  for (Node* ptr = array[0].next; ptr->next != nullptr; ptr = ptr->next)
    std::cout << ptr->value << " ";
  std::cout << "\n";
}

void swap(Node* array, int i, int j) {
  // Special Case 1: i == j
  if (i == j)
    return;
  Node* inode = &array[i+1];
  Node* jnode = &array[j+1];
  Node* iprev = inode->prev;
  Node* inext = inode->next;
  Node* jprev = jnode->prev;
  Node* jnext = jnode->next;
  // Special Case 1: i + 1 == j, resulting in [iprev jnode inode jnext]
  if (inode->next == jnode)
  {
    iprev->next = jnode;
    jnode->next = inode;
    inode->next = jnext;
    jnext->prev = inode;
    inode->prev = jnode;
    jnode->prev = iprev;
    return;
  }
  // Special Case 3: j+1 == i, resulting in [jprev inode jnode inext]
  if (jnode->next == inode)
  {
    jprev->next = inode;
    inode->next = jnode;
    jnode->next = inext;
    inext->prev = jnode;
    jnode->prev = inode;
    inode->prev = jprev;
    return;
  }
  // Default Case 4: Resulting in two sequences: [iprev jnode inext] and [jprev inode jnext]
  iprev->next = jnode;
  jnode->next = inext;
  jprev->next = inode;
  inode->next = jnext;
  jnext->prev = inode;
  inode->prev = jprev;
  inext->prev = jnode;
  jnode->prev = iprev;
}

void test()
{
  Node* array = new_array(4);
  print_array(array); // 10 20 30 40
  swap(array, 1, 3);
  print_array(array); // 10 40 30 20
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
  test();
  return 0;
}


When the nodes to be swapped are adjacent in the list order, i.e. where either array[i].next == &array[j] or vice versa, then after the memory swap, we will have array[j].next == &array[j] or similar self references. Your code will clearly bring havoc when dealing with this case.
You will have to detect this boundary case and deal accordingly. For instance, if could be done like this:
void swap(Node* array, int i, int j) {
  if (i == j)
    return;

  // Swap the nodes
  Node temp = array[i];
  array[i] = array[j];
  array[j] = temp;

  // Update next and prev pointers for array[i]
  if (array[i].next == &array[i]) {
    array[i].next = &array[j];
  } else if (array[i].next) {
    array[i].next->prev = &array[i];
  }
  if (array[i].prev == &array[i]) {
    array[i].prev = &array[j];
  } else if (array[i].prev) {
    array[i].prev->next = &array[i];
  }

  // Update next and prev pointers for array[j]
  if (array[j].next == &array[j]) {
    array[j].next = &array[i];
  } else if (array[j].next) {
    array[j].next->prev = &array[j];
  }
  if (array[j].prev == &array[j]) {
    array[j].prev = &array[i];
  } else if (array[j].prev) {
    array[j].prev->next = &array[j];
  }
}

Note that you will need to manage the pointer to the head/tail nodes in the list when they are involved in a swap like this. Also, if you have functions to insert/remove nodes, you'll need to manage a list of unused nodes, and take from and give back to that list as you logically insert or remove nodes from the logical list.
